# start-transcript does not capture 'Read-Host' in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture of logs of powershell Script but it does not capture "Read-Host" information. My Code looks like this:

```
#setting log files and path
$a=(Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy-hhmm')
$B='Fresh'+'-'+$a
$Logfile = ".\$B.log" 
Start-Transcript -Path $Logfile   

Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Blue "What is the name of the target RDS to be refreshed?"
$rdsid=Read-Host "Unique ID""

Stop-Transcript
```

But it does not log what was given against Read Host. My logs looks like this :

---

Transcript started, output file is .\refreshv5-05-26-2020-0827.log
What is the name of the target RDS to be refreshed?

---

and it does contain what value was passed against $rdsid

Comment: my understanding is that `Read-Host` s not seen by the transcript process since that is a direct-from-host-to-variable thing. i suspect you will need to write the value out after it is read.

Comment: This is annoying. Transcripts capture most things ... but not important things like this. And apparently it [used to](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da232d18-3f48-4ac1-863f-af662260f3c8/powershell-5x-transcript-not-capturing-user-input?forum=winserverpowershell) in older versions.